# Disabling command substitution in shell

Tags: bash, mercurial, ssh

I have an ssh box that runs Subversion and Mercurial services. On connection to this box, a script verifies that the user is only running mercurial or svn related commands:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    # Verify that the requested command is an svnserve call.
    #
    # Note that sshd stores the command requested by the client in
    # the variable "SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND".

    echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND | grep -E '^hg -R'
    ISHG=$?

    if [[ $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND = "svnserve -t" || $ISHG -eq 0 ]]
    then
            exec $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
    else
            echo "You are only allowed svn access to this server."
    fi
```

The problem is, hg verification is not very clean or secure. If I include backticks in my remote ssh command, the "echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" line will happily execute it. Does anyone have any suggestions for cleaning this up a little bit?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce in bash 4.1.5 - backticks are preserved by `exec $var`. (By the way, `[[` can do regex matching with `=~`.)

Comment: I think the first ECHO, where I pipe it into grep is the culprit. I had issues with =~, I should try it again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah. Don't use shell for that. Write a program in a language that would allow you to make sure that the only binaries it's going to execute are white-listed.

Comment: Seems like too much work to break out a C compiler for this..

Comment: Is Perl prohibited at your site? :)

Comment: @EightyEight: Nobody mentioned C.

Comment: @EightyEight Perl (IPC modules) or Python (subprocess) should both be pretty capable for this kind of thing.

Comment: Ah fair enough, perl it is. I'll try grawity's Bash =~ suggestion first though.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial comes with a tool for exactly this! Use the [`contrib/hg-ssh`](http://www.selenic.com/repo/hg/raw-file/stable/contrib/hg-ssh) script we provide to restrict the commands. The file contains this header to explain how to use it:

> To be used in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with the `command` option, see sshd(8):
>
> ```
> command="hg-ssh path/to/repo1 /path/to/repo2 ~/repo3 ~user/repo4" ssh-dss ...
> ```
>
> (probably together with these other useful options: `no-port-forwarding`, `no-X11-forwarding`, `no-agent-forwarding`)
>
> This allows pull/push over SSH from/to the repositories given as arguments.
>   If all your repositories are subdirectories of a common directory, you can
>   allow shorter paths with:
>
> ```
> command="cd path/to/my/repositories && hg-ssh repo1 subdir/repo2"
> ```
>
> You can use pattern matching of your normal shell, e.g.:
>
> ```
> command="cd repos && hg-ssh user/thomas/* projects/{mercurial,foo}"
> ```